# Space between last two rows in a table

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I need to provide a space between the last tr in the following table so that it feel like another block. The rows are generating in a loop. Any idea for the same?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last" style="border-top: 5px solid blue;">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way is provide an empty `<tr>` before last `<tr>` like below...

```html
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last" style="border-top: 5px solid blue;">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css

```
Table:last-child {
   padding-top: 8px; /* fill in your value */
 }
```

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you for putting [this](https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/essay.htm) into your profile's About me section! xD

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add padding/ margin just try both and check

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last" style="border-top: 5px solid blue;">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in css file

```
.last {

    padding-top: 5px;
   }
```

or you can give margin

```
 .last {

    margin-top: 5px;
   }
```

You can choose any one of above methods , either you can add padding or you can add margin  :) try this

Comment: Both padding and margin will not wok as expected

Comment: @sree then add -->    `table { border-collapse: collapse;}` in css

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` pseudo elements.

```
<style>
    .table-class tr:last-child {
        padding:10px; // your value.
    }
</style>
```